# warning no-method descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale found

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsdate

I am getting this warning in xcode 3.1.3 iphone os 3.0.

This method is also not available in the NSDate class. 
But I am getting the date from this method.

Can anyone please tell me How can I get rid of this warning????

Comment: Could you post the line of source code that's getting this warning, and if possible, the build command for the source file? Just drag and drop the "Compiling..." line from the Build Results window.

Answer (score 8):

You'll want to use NSDateFormatter instead.  descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale: landed on the "non-public API" list recently, and is grounds for rejection of your app.

Here's an example of how you can use NSDateFormatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d y"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
return dateString;
```

Note that the format string is the Unicode standard, not the printf-style version.  You can find the spec here: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 0):

These are undocumented private API methods. Using them will get your app rejected by Apple. Use only the documented methods of NSDate.